# In AFWall+, how do you block everything by default?

Tags: security, firewall

I want the default to be blocked unless I specifically allow that app. I understand you can tick all what you want blocked or not. But, what I want is for any app that gets installed to be automatically, completely, blocked from the git go - unless I get in AFWall+ and allow it. So if an app called X is installed, it wouldn't have any access to network *without* me having to block it. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: As it might prove helpful in addition, [here's a video tutorial](https://invidious.snopyta.org/watch?v=QcFfvYdgCgs) for AFWall+. And again, for German speakers the recommendation of Mike Kuketz' security blog series "Take back control": [AFWall+](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/afwall-digitaler-tuervorsteher-take-back-control-teil4/).

Answer (score 2):

Use it in "Allow selected" mode.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: And yes, good idea to allow AdAway (first entry in that list) access :D Just mention that effective ad blocker for the benefit of the OP so Kaftee can check that box on the question list (@Kaftee: you know what I mean: the "other" part. AdAway requires root, too, and effectively blocks requests to "bad domains").